# How is the naming of related_names in django model?

Tags: django-models

I have a model with a name that is comprised of two English nouns. My model name id DesignatedInstitution. Based on the convention of Django, I have to name it this way: without a hyphen and each word having first Capital Letter.
On the other hand, I have a field that specifies the city of the designated institution. I want to add related_name to the field. The best practice for related_name is using the lower case of the model name. But in this case, the nouns are not separated. so which one is better:

1-

```
class LearningInstitution(Model):
    city = CharField(City,related_name='learning_institutions')
```

OR

2-

```
class LearningInstitution(Model):
    city = CharField(City,related_name='learninginstitutions')
```

Note: In the documentation, it is explained that the related_name should be the plural but the lower case of the model name. However, when I go with the plural and lower case of the model name, Pycharm does not like it and underline it
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

I have searched StackOverflow and have read Django documentation but I did not find my answer.
I expect to be advised whether I should use option 1 or 2. Which one is better and be provided with an explanation of why that option is chosen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "primarily opinion-based" since there's absolutely no technical impact - it's just about naming. This being said and as far as I'm concerned, the only sensible choice is the first solution - the second one is totally unreadable.

Comment: In the documentation, it is explained that the related_name should be the plural but the lower case of the model name. However, when I go with the plural and lower case of the model name, Pycharm does not like it and underline it. I just added this explanation as a note below my question.

Comment: "In the documentation, it is explained that the related_name should be the plural but the lower case of the model name" => where exactly ? 

But anyway: while it indeed makes sense to use the lower_case (python naming convention, cf pep08) plural form (denotes a collection) of the model name, you are actually free to name it as you wish. wrt/ pycharm, it's just running some lint tool on your code, it's up to you to configure it how you want. When it comes to naming / code layout / etc, whatever the guidelines might say, the end goal is readability so by all means use your own judgement.